# VBA FilePicker no longer opening from ThisWork.Path

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a workbook (located on our network) with a macro enabled so I can email exported PDF worksheets via Outlook every Friday. The exported worksheet PDF gets saved to the same location as the Workbook. Outlook then opens the FilePicker and lets me select the file that I want to attach to the email. For some reason the Filepicker is now not opening to ThisWork.path anymore; it opens to my default MyDocuments located on my native computer. The exported file still saves in the proper spot (located on the network) but the FilePicker just wont open to that location. Now, if I move this Workbook to my direct computer, the FilePicker works as it should. I have not changed anything in the VBA so I don't know why this is all the sudden not working. It worked just last week. Below is the code I believe to be relevant to the issue.

```
   'Creates workpath string
    Dim mypath As String, fname As String
    mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    fname = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.Name)
'********************************************************
    'Saves PDF with Template Text and Date based on Order Date
    Sheets(1).ExportAsFixedFormat 0, mypath & "\" & "TEXT Order Sheet  " & Format(Range("D7").Value, "mm-dd-yy")
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Range("D7").Value, "mm-dd-yy")
'********************************************************
Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xFilePath As String
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileDlgItem As Variant
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    xFileDlg.Filters.Clear
    xFileDlg.Filters.Add "pdf files", "*.pdf"
    xFileDlg.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    If xFileDlg.Show = -1 Then
'********************************************************
        With xMailOut
         .Display
            .To = "fake@email.com"
            .Subject = "TEXT" & Range("D7").Value
            .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:12.0pt'>" & "Here is our TEXT order for the week of " & Range("D7").Value & "." & " Please respond to this email to confirm that you have received the order." & .HTMLBody
                        For Each xFileDlgItem In xFileDlg.SelectedItems
                .Attachments.Add xFileDlgItem
            Next xFileDlgItem
            .Display
        End With
    End If
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'********************************************************
```

Comment: What line does it fail on? Sometimes things get jammed up in memory, and if you restart the machine, the memory gets flushed, and it may start working again. If it worked last week, but not now, for no apparent reason, you can try this option and see how it works out for you.

Comment: Office applications were designed to deal with a local file system only. I'd recommend copying the file to the local machine and then run the VBA macro from there initializing the dialog with a local path.

Comment: ASH, I tried your suggestion to restart the computer but unfortunately it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev which is a fair point. But it is just odd that this VBA code has worked for months up until last week.

Comment: I figured out a temporary work around, if I use the network file directory address     (xFileDlg.InitialFileName = "ECT-NAS\Folder\") of the folder in question the code works properly. Its not ideal but it works for now.